# How to prevent a group of buttons from wrapping in the mui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Expected result:
[image]

My code:

[image]
[image]

```
<Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between", marginTop: 2, width: "100%", overflowX: "scroll" }}>
                <Button variant="outlined" size="small" endIcon={<KeyboardArrowDown />}>Departure at 21:37</Button>
                <Button variant="outlined" size="small" endIcon={<KeyboardArrowDown />}>The lowest cost</Button>
                <Button variant="outlined" size="small" endIcon={<KeyboardArrowDown />}>Options</Button>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex: none;` on the buttons.

```
<Box
  sx={{
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginTop: 2,
    width: "100%",
    overflowX: "scroll",
    button: {
      flex: "none"
    }
  }}
>
  <Button variant="outlined" size="small" endIcon={<KeyboardArrowDown />}>
    Departure at 21:37
  </Button>
  <Button variant="outlined" size="small" endIcon={<KeyboardArrowDown />}>
    The lowest cost
  </Button>
  <Button variant="outlined" size="small" endIcon={<KeyboardArrowDown />}>
    Options
  </Button>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add nowrap to button

```
<Button sx={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}>Button Text</Button>
```

Add flexwrap to Box styles

```
<Box sx={{flexWrap: "wrap"}}>
  <Button sx={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}>Button Text</Button>
</Box>
```